# setting up Phabricator with github

Tags: phabricator

I'm trying to set up Phabricator to work with github, but I have no idea what I should add at the step where I have to enter Github SSH Key credentials:

[image: Phabricator SSH configuration]

Should I enter my username and SSH key from my local computer?

What is password for key?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

- Name and description are whatever you want.
- Username is whatever your Github username is.
- Private Key is a private SSH key from your local computer.
- Password for Key is the passphrase you entered when generating that key.

Entering your SSH key from your local computer is fine, but it's better practice to generate a new one specifically for Phabricator and then add it to your Github account (so that if you need to deauthorize Phabricator only, you can do so). If you're on Linux or Mac, ssh-keygen will do the trick to create a new key pair; on Windows, Github's git bash client will work. In that case, you will need to [add the public key to your Github SSH keys](https://github.com/settings/ssh).

The password was set when you created the key pair (SSH usually calls it "passphrase"). If you don't know it, try leaving it blank - it's not mandatory, so your key may not have it. If that doesn't work and you can't find the password, you can always just create a new key as described above and then add it to your Github account.